# Passing buffer to function for writing

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, dynamic, malloc

I'm trying to implement a quick prototype program to prepare a message that I intend to use as a tcp socket communication protocol.
I'm new at this, and I can't quite understand why running the following prints (null). Am I failing at passing the pointer to the subroutine?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const char *header = "testhd";

void pack_message(char *body, char *buffer)
{
    size_t body_size, msg_size, buffer_size;
    char hex_size[11];
    
    body_size = strlen(body);
    snprintf(hex_size, 11, "0x%x", body_size);
    msg_size = 16 + body_size;
    buffer_size = msg_size + 1;
    
    if (!buffer){
        buffer = malloc(buffer_size);
    }else{
        buffer = realloc(buffer, buffer_size);
    }
    
    memset(buffer, 0, buffer_size);
    
    strcat(buffer, header);
    strcat(buffer, hex_size);
    strcat(buffer, body);
}

int main(){
    char *buffer = NULL;
    char *body = "testmsg";
    pack_message(body, buffer);
    printf("%s", buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Remember that arguments in C are pass *by value*. That means the value in the call is *copied* into the functions local argument variable. Any changes to the local argument variable, like assigning to it, will only happen to that local variable. The original value used in the call will not be affected. Please research *emulating pass by reference in C*. Hint: It involves pointers and the pointer-to operator `&`.

Comment: When you've figured out the buffer problem, you still need to deal with free'ing the alloc'd block (or the program will leak memory...)

Comment: Can you not declare (or allocate) a sufficiently large buffer in the caller, then have your 'pack' function fill-in as much as it needs (not overflowing!)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that `char *buffer` in `main` function and `char *buffer` in `pack_message` function are two different pointers which are pointing to the same `NULL` address.
So in Your case functiom `pack_message` is working with local pointer and that's the reason why running Your code prints `null`.

To make Your code work You could potentially take an approach where You pass an address of pointer itself as an argument to the `pack_message` function so `main` function could look like that:

```
int main(){
    char *buffer = NULL;
    char *body = "testmsg";
    pack_message(body, &buffer);
    printf("%s", buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Your `pack_message` function should be changed to:

```
void pack_message(char *body, char **buffer)
{
    size_t body_size, msg_size, buffer_size;
    char hex_size[11];
    
    body_size = strlen(body);
    snprintf(hex_size, 11, "0x%zx", body_size);
    msg_size = 16 + body_size;
    buffer_size = msg_size + 1;
    
    if (NULL == *buffer){
        *buffer = malloc(buffer_size);
    }else{
        *buffer = realloc(*buffer, buffer_size);
    }
    
    memset(*buffer, 0, buffer_size);
    
    strcat(*buffer, header);
    strcat(*buffer, hex_size);
    strcat(*buffer, body);
}
```

Please note that there I changed also one more potential issue:

```
snprintf(hex_size, 11, "0x%zx", body_size);
```

As `body_size` is of type `size_t` it is better idea to use `%zx` as `size_t` can be different size than `unsigned integer`, for details on printf please take a look at: https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Similar approach can be taken to `char *body = "testmsg";` especially when its value will be much longer string.
For further improvements I would recommend to redesign `pack_message` function to return a pointer to allocated buffer as it will lower the chances to forget about freeing memory when not needed anymore.

Comment: I had tried this before (simulating passing by reference) but I was getting an error from realloc, not realizing that both the old and the new parameters needed to be dereferenced. Now it's working, thanks! Just to clarify. The check for null pointer in pack (the if block), should that also be "if (!*pointer)" meaning dereferenced?

Comment: You are right. I missed that and in fact it is not recommended to treat `null` the same as `false` in boolean context.

Comment: Oh ok, I saw a pretty widespread practice of testing for null pointer directly instead of ==Null but I guess that assumes null=0 which is implementation -dependent?

Comment: I would say it is more about readability because when You see comparison against 'NULL' you can understand faster that this is about pointers and not regular variable. As You mentioned there is also this very very rare scenario where 'NULL' might be something different than zero. As in practice null pointer points to non-existent address, so when called as function pointer You have undefined behavior. You might want to catch such event on software level without relying on hardware executing fault handler.